# Extract string before a specified character

Tags: windows, powershell

I have multiple returning types value when retrieving a machine name.
For example, machine1 and machine1.contoso.local.

I set $1 to a list of computers like this `$1 = get-computernamelist` but I need it to be consistent with the machine name part which comes under the property name in the cmdlet.

How do I extract the string from the machine1.contoso.local before the first full stop? If I could set `$1 = get-computernamelist` before the first full stop if one exists that would do the job nicely.

Comment: Use string manipulation or standardized machine names.

Comment: You could split on ? `.`, select the first item in the array and use a calculated property to store it in your variable: `$1 = get-computernamelist | select-object @{'n'='ComputerName';'e'={$_.Name.split(".")[0]}}`

Answer (score 0):

To parse the host name from the FQDN in Powershell you can use  `SubString` together with `IndexOf`:

```
$hoststring = "machine1.contoso.com"
$hostname = $hoststring.SubString(0, $hoststring.IndexOf("."))
```

Not knowing exactly what the output of `get-computernamelist` looks like it's hard to give you a more detailed answer.  There will be different methods of parsing the entire list depending on what kind of list it is, but each will include parsing like the above.

Comment: Thanks for this it helps a lot, I think you can say get-computernamelist is the same kind of output list as Get-ADComputer -Filter * - Property * , and the property name is what I'm interested in and that's where the difference in FQDN and NETBIOS name is found for different machines.